# Clone Label, Button and Textbox by pressing a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, clone

I'm trying to write a simple stock counting program.
Created a line where you can put the article name and add, take away or reset the value.
I would like to add a button that will clone the whole row and paste a new one below it.
I could increase the number of counters and just copy and paste part of the code with the new counter number. Not very convenient to adjust the code when a new entry will arrive. 
Here is my program so far no clue how to approach it, any help much appreciated:

```
import tkinter
import sys

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
root.title("Counter")
counter = tkinter.IntVar()


def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)

tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=counter).place(x=480, y=20)


tkinter.Button(root, text="+1", command=onClick, fg="dark green", bg = "white").place(x=520, y=20)
def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 10)
tkinter.Button(root, text="+10", command=onClick, fg="dark green", bg = "white").place(x=560, y=20)

def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() - 1)


tkinter.Button(root, text="-1", command=onClick, fg="dark red", bg = "white").place(x=440, y=20)
def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() - 10)
tkinter.Button(root, text="-10", command=onClick, fg="dark red", bg = "white").place(x=400, y=20)


def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get()-counter.get()) 

tkinter.Button(root, text="Reset", command=onClick, fg="Black", bg = "white").place(x=620, y=20)



T = tkinter.Text(root, height=1, width=40)

    T.place(x=10, y=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: create function which doesn't clone but create new widgets with new values.

Comment: to clone something you would have to first assign it to (global) variable. Currently you don't assign widgets to any varialbles so you don't have access to them to clone them. But instead of cloning you should rather create new one.

Comment: you shouldn't create many functions with the same name - `onClick`. In some moment it is hard to say which function is used by button. Better create `onClickAdd1`, `onClickAdd10` or use `lambda` to assign to button the same function but with different argument `command=lambda:onClickAdd(10)`, `command=lambda:onClickAdd(1)`

Comment: you can also use `Frame` to create own widget with `Label`, `Text` and some code and then you have to create this widget when you press button. And you will have to hide only this widget when you will hide row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clone you would have to first keep widgets in (global) variables.

But instead of cloning you should create function which creates new `Label`, `Text`, `Button` when you press button.

But instead of creating `Label`, `Text`, `Button` you can also use `tkinter.Frame` to define own widget - ie. `class Row` - and then you have to only create `Row` when you press button. Widget can also has own `counter` to keep value only for this row.

---

I define class `Row` which use `Frame` to keep `Label`, `Text`, `Button` and `IntVar`. And I can create new `Row` everytime when I press button `"Add row"`

I also use `pack()` instead of `place()` so I don't have to calculate `x`, `y`

I keep rows on list so I can get `counter` from every row and sum them.

```
import tkinter
import sys

# --- classes ----

class Row(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, row_number):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.counter = tkinter.IntVar()

        tkinter.Label(self, text=str(row_number)).pack(side='left')

        t = tkinter.Text(self, height=1, width=40)
        t.pack(side='left')

        tkinter.Button(self, text="+1",  command=lambda:self.add(1)).pack(side='left')
        tkinter.Button(self, text="+10", command=lambda:self.add(10)).pack(side='left')

        tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.counter).pack(side='left')

        tkinter.Button(self, text="-1",  command=lambda:self.add(-1)).pack(side='left')
        tkinter.Button(self, text="-10", command=lambda:self.add(-10)).pack(side='left')
        tkinter.Button(self, text="Reset", command=self.set).pack(side='left')

    def add(self, value):
        self.counter.set(self.counter.get() + value)

    def set(self, value=0):
        self.counter.set(value) 

# --- functions ---

def add_row():
    number = len(all_rows) + 1
    row = Row(root, number)
    row.pack()
    all_rows.append(row)

def sum_rows():
    # get counters from all rows and sum them
    label_sum['text'] = sum(row.counter.get() for row in all_rows)

# --- main ---

all_rows = []

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
root.title("Counter")

tkinter.Button(root, text='Add row', command=add_row).pack()
tkinter.Button(root, text='Sum rows', command=sum_rows).pack()

label_sum = tkinter.Label(root, text='')
label_sum.pack()

add_row() # one row at start

root.mainloop()
```